# How to build only a specific tenant in HYBRIS?

Tags: java, ant, build, devops, sap-commerce-cloud

I have three different tenant present inside the custom folder.

```
<HYBRIS_HOME>/bin/custom
            |
            |
tenant1  tenant2 tenant3
```

Whenever I execute `ant clean all` it builds all three tenants.
Is there a way to only build one tenant at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of the box option to build only extensions of a specific tenant.

By default hybris build all extensions mentionned in `localextensions.xml` with their dependencies.

You have a workaround although.

- you can have several `localextensions.xml` and switch them with a script
- you can use `ant extensionsxml -Dplatform.extensions="ext1 ext2" -Dplatform.extensionsgen.filename=localextensions.xml` to generated the extensions file for your tenant specific extensions

Comment: So, there's now way to do it through a single `localextensions.xml` and `local.properties` file?

Comment: Ootb no, but you can customize your ant buildcallbacks.xml in each extension. You may want to add "tenant parameter" and perform the build only if the desired tenant is passed in parameter. Check this post about if/else in ant. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14500576/1140748